# preg_match gives different results than perl string match

Tags: php, perl

I would like to capture room number from a string and condition is (start with a # and end with a space or comma).

My php code is:

```
 preg_match('/(#.*?)[ ,]/',
   '112 east coast road #b1-15, 112 katong, singapore 428802', $match);
 if($match) {
 echo "match=".$match[0];
 }
 else {
   echo 'not match';
 }
```

The output is: `<code>match=#b1-15,</code>`

As you can see, a comma is captured.

While I use the same pattern in perl
     use strict;

```
my $str = "112 east coast road #b1-15, 112 katong, singapore 428802";

if($str =~ /(#.*?)[ ,]/) {
    print "match = $1";
}
else {
    print "not match";
}
```

The output is: `<code>match = #b1-15</code>`

Could anybody tell me why and how to correct my PHP pattern matching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is returning two matches as you can check running this:

```
preg_match('/(#.*?)[ ,]/','112 east coast road #b1-15, 112 katong, singapore    428802', $match);
```

var_dump($match);

The result is:

```
array(2) {[0]=>string(7) "#b1-15,"[1]=>string(6) "#b1-15"}
```

The first match is the "global" match of your regex the second corresponds to the first group.

Answer (score 1):

They actually do the same. Only the information returned to you is different.

`preg_match` returns an array of matches. Your match check outputs the fully matched pattern.

The return of `preg_match` will be

```
array(2
    0   =>  #b1-15,
    1   =>  #b1-15
)
```

The first array value is the full matched pattern. The second one is the first captured parenthesized subpattern and so on.

Please refer to
http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

See the section about parameter `matches`